# VB.net Module returning data like a function

Tags: vb.net, function, module, return

How could I call a module or something else to return data to me after its ran. I don't want to make my form1 code all messy.

Thanks!

Example by what I mean return:

```
Public Function Test() As String
    Return "Tes34t"
End Function

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MessageBox.Show(Test)
End Sub
```

Comment: A slightly off-topic advice: give your form a nicer name. Form1 does not describe anything.

Comment: @Gertjan: You cannot tell what the name of the Form is from the sample code. The name of the method that handles the form's `Load` event is "Form1_Load".

Comment: @AMissico: Yes you can, first of all Visual Studio will create names of events according to the form name plus user is xzerox says: "I don't want to make my form1 code all messy.". Apart from that it is only an advice, good coding begins with clean code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Test` is in the same class (Form1), then just use

```
MessageBox.Show(Test())
```

If it's in module "MyModule", then use

```
MessageBox.Show(MyModule.Test())
```

Comment: Great anwer, guess nobody would think the person asking the question would overlook that. I was thinking he would like a possibility to dynamically call a function, but it was this simple :)